# R- Graphing continuous data as a barplot with nonequal subsets

Tags: r

I am looking to display a dataset as a barplot in order to show that some domains of data have more range variation than others.  Although I have found ways to set up a barplot where the data domain is broken down into a number of equal subsets, I have not been able to find a way to dictate the numerical cutoffs of these subsets.  The cut() function has been giving me some trouble, but that may just be because I am relatively new to R.

The scatterplot representation of the dataset I am working with is:  [zooplankton.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p59gp.png).  I would like to be able to display the average species diversity score for each discrete pH score, such that the average score for pH <4, pH <= 4 | pH < 5, etc. each is its own bar.

The way I have been trying to solve this is by using:

```
pH.bins<-cut(zoo$pH, c(3,4,5,6,7,8))

bar.pH <- tapply(zoo$Species.Diversity, list(zoo$pH.bins), mean)

barplot(bar.pH, 
    main="Average Species Diversity Score by pH", 
    xlab = "pH",
    ylab = "Average Species Diversity",
    col = "blue",
    ylim = c(3,8))
par(new=F)
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error telling my that my tapply() arguments need to be the same length, and I am not sure how to proceed.  Suggestions?